# Change weekday name to a specific pattern

Tags: r

I have a database that has a `Week` column. Weekday names are Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc. However, I would like to automatically change this to the following: `Week = c("monday day","tuesday day","wednesday day","thursday day","friday day" "saturday","sunday day" )` . In this case below, as my database only has two days of the week, only Monday and Sunday will be changed. How to adjust this?

```
 Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-18","2021-10-18","2021-10-28","2021-10-30")),
                       Week = c("Monday", "monday", "Sunday", "Sunday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "FDE", "FDE", "FDE"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: You may use `paste` i.e. `Test$Week <- paste(Test$Week, "day")`

Comment: Alternatively, using `gsub`, you could run `Test$Week <- gsub('y$', 'y day', Test$Week)`

Comment: Thanks for reply!. I ended up incorrectly entering the names I want to update in the `Week`. Can you please look again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backreference `\\1` to refer back to the `Week` value given and add  `day` to it in `sub`'s replacement clause:

```
Test$Week <- tolower(sub("^(.*)$", "\\1 day", Test$Week))
```

Result:

```
Test 
       date1      date2       Week Category time
1 2021-11-01 2021-10-18 monday day      FDE    4
2 2021-11-01 2021-10-18 monday day      FDE    6
3 2021-11-01 2021-10-28 sunday day      FDE    6
4 2021-11-01 2021-10-30 sunday day      FDE    3
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you want to use the values of `Temp$Week` and add ' day' to each value. This is easily accomplished by running:

```
Test$Week <- gsub('y$', 'y day', Test$Week)

> Test$Week
[1] "Monday day" "monday day" "Sunday day" "Sunday day"
```

If you would like to have all days of the week (i.e. `length(Test$Week)` would equal 7), then the following should work:

```
temp <- c(paste0('2021-12-', 27:31), '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02')
Test$Week <- strftime(temp, '%A')
Test$Week <- gsub('y$', 'y day', Test$Week)
```

Comment: Your code not worked. When I run:  `Test$Week <- strftime(temp, '%A')`, it appears a error: `Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, Week, value = c(...) replacement has 7 rows, data has 4`.  Did you test for that database there that I entered in the question and did it work for you?

Comment: I thought that you wanted the names of all seven days of the week followed by ' day'. I adapted the answer, so that it now works for both scenarios. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just use:

```
library(tidyverse)

Test %>%
   mutate(Week = paste(tolower(Week), "day"))
```